# accessing "TaskbarIcon" in View from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn

I have a View, called MyView, that looks like this

```
<Grid>
    <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Name="MyTaskBar"
                    IconSource="/Icons/Icon.ico"
                    MenuActivation="LeftOrRightClick">

        <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="About" cal:Message.Attach="About">
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>

    </tb:TaskbarIcon>
</Grid>
```

In the view's "code behind", I can open a balloon notification with:

```
var myBalloon = new MyBalloonView();
MyTaskBar.ShowCustomBalloon(myBalloon, PopupAnimation.Slide, 100);
```

How can I access the "MyTaskBar" in the MyViewModel? I am using Caliburn.